# IBAction called with sender disabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uibutton, ibaction

In which circumstance can a IBAction be called by cocoa with the sender disabled?

I have the following code

```
- (IBAction)onMuteTap:(UIButton*)sender {
    if (!sender.enabled) {
        // Whatever 1
    }
    // Whatever 2
}
```

I had put a breakpoint in `Whatever 1`, which is sometimes called if I keep pressing the linked button.
This `if` is just for debug sake, because I've assumed the IBAction would never be called with a disabled sender, which seemed to be a false assumption.

Just a complementary info, the button was explicitly disabled by me in another part of the code with

```
...
muteButton.enabled = NO;
...
```

[EDIT] Both codes are running in the main thread.

[The sender has the same address of _muteButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9p9c.png)

Comment: There is code. Whatever 1 is any code. It's is a NSLog in fact.

Comment: Does the button look disabled? Is `muteButton.enabled = NO;` called on the main thread? Are `muteButton` and `sender` the same address?

Comment: I'm dismissing the view some instants later, so it is hard to see. Let me try to don't dismiss and see the button.
Both codes are running on the main thread.
I will check the addresses, but even if they weren't, the sender is surely disabled. I will attach a ss of the debugger.

Comment: When you tap the button, does it _look_ disabled? A disabled button is very visibly disabled (faded text etc.). — Also, you say "I'm dismissing the view some instants later, so it is hard to see" — what does _that_ mean? It sounds like some kind of hanky-panky is going on that you have not described for us.

Comment: The button looks disabled after that (I cannot click it anymore too). It looks too much as a race condition, but everything is running on the main thread...

Comment: _After_ that? Okay, so it _was_ enabled when you tapped it, but by the time your `lldb` session took place, something else had disabled it.

Comment: @matt The dismissal is of the parent view (changing screens). It is not really related. I can remove it and the problem persists.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you really _do_ have a race condition. Put a symbolic breakpoint on `-[UIControl setEnabled:]` and find out.

Answer (score 0):

`IBAction` is just a method like any other. You can call it like any other method. So if you pass a disabled control as parameter:

```
button.enabled = NO;
[self onMuteTap:button];
```

you get your "sender disabled".

Comment: Indeed, I was not specific enough. The call was made by cocoa. The only one calling this method is the UI.
Let me edit my question.